# Manually configure network adapters on Android Things

Tags: android, networking, kotlin, raspberry-pi3, android-things

I am trying to configure an Android Things client running on a Raspberry Pi 3b to connect to a third party device on a different network. I did hours of research, but couldn´t find a working solution.

**Topology**

The Topology consists of one Raspberry PI, the router and a third party device.
The Raspberry PI is connected to the router via LAN and WLAN for failure safety and is part of the same network as the router.

**The Problem**

There is a third party device physically connected to the same router, but it has a different network configured. The configuration of the device can not be changed. *Please have a look at the topology below.*

I am able to connect to the third party device using MacOS or Windows by setting a static IP and changing the subnet mask of the network adapter to the same as the target.

**The question:** Is there a way to configure Android Things or modify the topology to access this device? (See red line in topology)

**Note: I am aware of the messy way how this connection should work ✌**

[image: Topology]

Comment: 3rd party device can run android os?

Comment: Nop, this device maybe runs on some sort of Linux, but I can´t make any changes to it. Just need to establish a socket connection fetch data from the API.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to refer to **`LoWPAN`** package from android things.

This package has several class which can help you to achieve your goal.

"*How you can achieve this?*", read below:

1. You can create a scan operation using [`LowpanScanner`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/things/lowpan/LowpanScanner) class which will provide you callback from [`LowpanScanner.Callback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/things/lowpan/LowpanScanner.Callback) class with [`LowpanBeaconInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/things/lowpan/LowpanBeaconInfo).
2. Now use [`LowpanIdentity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/things/lowpan/LowpanIdentity) class object for network info provided from [getLowpanIdentity()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/things/lowpan/LowpanBeaconInfo.html#getLowpanIdentity()) method of `LowpanBeaconInfo` class.
3. How you should connect to device in this provided network? Try to join them using [`LowpanProvisioningParams`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/things/lowpan/LowpanProvisioningParams) class if it helps.

Reference to 
[**com.google.android.things.lowpan**](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/things/lowpan/package-summary#classes)

***Note:*** (personally, i have't tried it out but hoping that it's the best shot which would work for you, let me know if it works or not)

I know it's not much but hope this helps !

---

> ### More about LoWPAN:
>
> **LoWPAN** is an acronym of **IPv6** over "Low-Power Wireless Personal Area Networks". It was originated from the idea that "the Internet
>   Protocol could and should be applied even to the smallest devices,"
>   and that low-power devices with limited processing capabilities should
>   be able to participate in the **Internet of Things**.
>
> LoWPAN group has defined encapsulation and header compression
>   mechanisms that allow IPv6 packets to be sent and received over **IEEE
>   802.15.4 based networks**. **IPv4** and **IPv6** are the work horses for data delivery for local-area networks, metropolitan area networks,
>   and wide-area networks such as the Internet. Likewise, IEEE 802.15.4
>   devices provide sensing communication-ability in the wireless domain.
>   The inherent natures of the two networks though, are different.
>   Read More from [**here**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6LoWPAN).

Comment: I think this won´t work, because the 3rd party device doesn´t got a WiFi interface.

Comment: What it you connect to router and get it's info to connect to device by https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/things/pio/package-summary this package.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to setup a virtual network, so you can use both, from adb shell execute this with "su" privileges:

```
ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.50.53 netmask 255.255.255.0
```